# How to trace logs in open faas serverless application?

Tags: kubernetes, workflow, serverless, minikube, openfaas

I am using OpenFaas functions to dpeloy a serverless application. KUbernetes cluster is being used for deployment via minikube. I want to trace the function calls, however any changes made inside build are not getting reflected in the kubernetes logs. Any updations on the Handler file is not getting reflected on to the ouput from the curl command that is calling it? How can I trace the function calls?

I tried checking logs in var/logs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check logs using `faas-cli logs [function-name]` command.